# List<Serializable> vs List<? extends Serializable>

Tags: java

I'm writing a method in Java that must receive and iterate over a `List` of `Serializable`.
What's the difference between:

```
public void myMethod(List<Serializable> list) {

}
```

and

```
public void myMethod(List<? extends Serializable> list) {

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the first case, the list given to the method **must** be `List<Serializable>`. In the second case, it can be that, or `List<AnythingThatDerivesFromSerializable>`. (In the specific case of `Serializable`, it's unlikely to be much difference.)

Let's do the general case:

```
class Base {
}

class Sub extends Base {
}
```

and then

```
public void myMethod(List<Base> list) {
}
```

If I had a `List<Sub>`, I couldn't give it to `myMethod`. But if you do:

```
public void myMethod(List<? extends Base> list) {
}
```

I can.

Answer (score 5):

`List<Serializable> list` means you can only send `List<Serializable>` parameter or a class that implements `List<Serializable>` like `ArrayList<Serializable>`.

`List<? extends Serializable> list` means you can send a `List<Whatever>` as long as `Whatever` implements the `Serializable` interface e.g. `List<String>`.

Answer (score 1):

`List<? extends Serializable>` will allow the caller to pass in a list of any *subtype* of `Serializable`.  This is generally more flexible than requiring an exact type match.

Note, however, that using an *extends* wildcard on `List<E>` will restrict the operations you can perform.  Specifically, you will not be able to call any instance method that has a parameter type containing the bounded generic parameter.  For example, you cannot call `list.add(E)` because it has a parameter type `E` (which you bounded with a wildcard), but you could call `get(int)`.

The rule of thumb for collections with an *extends* wildcard is that you can pull values *out* of the collection, but you cannot put values *in*.  If all you are doing is reading from the list, then you should go with the wildcard.